# Getting Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE while decommissioning a node

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a cassandra cluster of 10 machines with a replication factor of 3 on a keyspace .

I decommissioned a node using nodetool decommission command but it resulted in read failures with error 
`Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE while decommissioning a node`

This shouldn't happen because replication factor is 3 so at least one of those three nodes should have responded even if rebalancing is being done .

Any reason why this can happen

Answer (score 0):

When decommissioning a node or adding a node Actual consistency is considered to be +1.
This is explained [here](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000776006-Number-of-replicas-required-does-not-match-the-CL-being-used).